# Check if a string is or contains a comment in Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, comments, octave

Is there a way in Matlab or Octave to check if a string is or contains a comment? Some similar to `iscomment()`.

It is easy to check in the case we deal with comment lines where the comment identifier is at the beginning, using first `strtrim()` for blank elimination and then `strfind()` for search the comment identifier. But the problem is difficult when a comment is after a sentence or when the comment character is used in the string with other meaning, as, for example, in the fprintf() function for data format definition

Comment: Just wondering: Why do you want to know this? Do you mean an actual [string](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/strings.html), or a line of code?

Comment: I need to read a data file, in which I want to permit the user put comments (and blank lines)

Comment: have you seen this: http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2009/07/17/want-to-get-rid-of-your-code-comments/ and http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/110086-how-to-delete-all-the-commented-content-in-a-m-file, both refer to: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4645---matlab-comment-stripping-toolbox

Comment: `textscan` + `'commentStyle'` is another option for some cases.